# What is PermutedVarDeltaError in Random Forest?

Tags: matlab, random-forest

In MATLAB, the `TreeBagger` class provides a property `PermutedVarDeltaError` to measure the variable importance. I have gone through the provided definition several times:

> For any variable, the measure is the increase in prediction error if
>   the `values of that variable are permuted across the observations`.
>   This measure is computed for every tree, then averaged over the entire
>   ensemble and divided by the standard deviation over the entire
>   ensemble.

I am having trouble understanding the section `values of that variable are permuted across the observations`. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you have a dataset containing N variables and M observations, and you train a model on it (it doesn't really have to be a `TreeBagger`).

Now imagine that you take a single variable, and you randomly reorder (*permute*) all of its M values, while keeping the rest of the dataset in the same order. You retrain the model.

If the new model's accuracy suddenly dropped (i.e. its *error* had a large *delta*), then that variable would obviously have been important for the accuracy of the original model.

By contrast, if the new model's accuracy remained pretty similar even though you'd randomly reordered that variable's values, then the variable can't have been very important in the first place.

So this measure `PermutedVarDeltaError` (the difference in model error when permuting the values of a specific variable) is a measure of the importance of that variable.

Now it gets a little more complicated with `TreeBagger`, as this is an ensemble model composed of multiple submodels. But the basic thing is the same - you just measure it for each submodel, and then take an average across models, normalize it by the standard deviation, and you have a measure for the overall ensemble.

Comment: When you say `reorder/permute` the values of a variable, do you mean : `for each record, replace the value of the variable with some other value from variables range`. Does this mean that the original dataset and the new-dataset (after permutation are different dataset?

Comment: No, we're not picking new values, we're just reordering the existing values. In this way we ensure that the permuted variable has the same sample distribution as the original variable. The new dataset is different from the original one, but only this variable has changed.

Comment: Please include this information in your answer, so that I can mark it accepted.
On a side note: how accurate this measure will be when the variables and binary variables with heavy bias to one value

Comment: @Suryavanshi Sorry for the delay. So "accurate" isn't the right word here. `PermutedVarDeltaError` measures the change in model error when a variable has its values permuted, and it always does that. That may or may not be your preferred measure of the "importance" of a variable, or even of the "relative importance" of variables compared to each other. If your variables have differing properties, such as binary and continuous, or equally/unequally distributed values, you may not feel that it's a useful measure. But it still measures the change in error when a variable has its values permuted.